# iOS & SwipeView: not key value coding compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm more or less new to iOS development.

I downloaded the following repository to include in my project:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

It includes a horizontal paging view and bases on a xib File (exampleViewController) which is being loaded in the mainWindow.xib file (hopefully I have understood that right!).
I want to incorporate it in my app and would like to do so without the xib, since I'm using a storyboard. The view should be activated upon a button push.

Now I figured it would suffice to transfer the viewController class, include it in a storyboard viewController and to include the swipeView in it.

(the same logic, as by my understanding, is applied by the xibs.)

The only other change I applied was transferring the contents of the awakeFromNib  in the viewDidLoad.

Building the project then yields this error:

this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.

The first stackoverflow results haven't been really useful to me - does anybody have some input maybe?

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means, you have a property (delegate in your case) that is present in the storyboard, but not in the code of your class. Right click on the controller in the storyboard to open the black info window, and see if there is a property called delegate there that has a yellow warning triangle next to it. If so, delete the connection, or add that property to your class.